# Getting posted value (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am building a `DropDownList` control dynamically.

Constraining this discussion to within just the `OnInit()` method / state in the asp.net lifecycle, is the only way to see the dropdownlist's posted value to look at the `Request.Form` NameValueCollection?

I.e. Im aware that the dropdownlist's viewstate is restored by the time `OnLoad()` is reached, but I need it's value before then (im pretty sure LoadViewState($object) is of no use?)

Comment: Will the selectedvalue do it for you?

Comment: @IrishChieftain: Will it do what? At the OnInit stage the selectedvalue will contain the value i originally initialized the dropdownlist with, not the value the user just posted.

Comment: @Student: OnLoad / Page_Load is the same thing, I want the posted value before then without looking for a raw version in the request.form nvc.

Comment: can you explain why you need the value so early?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use `Request.Form`?

Answer (score 0):

try page_preload event to read viewstate

```
Private Sub Page_PreLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad
        Dim s As String = DropDownList1.Text
End Sub
```

Other solution could be
Try this in Init event

VB

```
dim s as string = Request.Params("DropDownList1")
```

C#

```
string s = Request.Params["DropDownList1"];
```

Comment: in Page_PreLoad viewstate is available and it will fire before Page_Load event.